# Does anyone know what the bija mantra KRAM stands for? Thank you

Tags: mantras, rituals, practice, yoga

I received it in a dream, that was very complex, and would like to clarify it

Comment: I am assuming it to be like KRAM -> क्रम -> This means sequence or order of things. I am not sure what a bija mantra is.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal No its kraam only not kram. Its a Bija mantra used in kara nyasa, anga nyasa during Goddess Kali's worship.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks for correcting my assumption.